# how to sort a list then sort a subset of that list

Tags: c#, linq, list, sorting

I have a collection of lines. Each line is a collection of fields. It is very easy to find column 1 and sort by its content:

```
_lines = lines.OrderBy(l => l.Fields.Find(f => f.ColumnNumber == 1).Content).ToList();
```

But how do I then sort a subset of this list? I want to sort by f.ColumnNumber == 3 where (f.ColumnNumber == 1).Content is 6.

So my line collection looks like this:

```
Col1, Col2, Col3

1, data, data
5, data, data
6, data, Chuck
6, data, Chuck
6, data, Jeffster
6, data, Jeffster
6, data, Grunke
6, data, Gertrude
8, data, data
9, data, data
```

I want to sort by col1, then sort only col1's where col1 == 6 but sort by col3.

Is there a way to do this in c#? I can't seem to find the magic formula.

EDIT:

My sample data is a little over simplified. Some lines have 3 columns, other lines have more or less columns. So when I use the .ThenBy extention, if I am trying to subsort lines on col 3 but say line 9 only has one column, I get an object reference not set to an instance of an object exception.

Here is a better example of the sample data:

```
Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4

1, data, data, data
5, data, data
6, data, Chuck
6, data, Chuck
6, data, Jeffster
6, data, Jeffster
6, data, Grunke
6, data, Gertrude
8, data, data
9, data

Code 1 lines have 4 columns.
Code 5 lines have 3.
Code 6 lines have 3 - and I need to sort by col 3 alphabetically.
Code 8 lines have 3 columns.
Code 9 lines have 2.
```

There is no guarantee the list is sorted at all. So I need first of all to have the lines sorted by that first column 1 - 9, then I need only code 6's to be sorted by col 3.

EDIT 2:

My class structure is somewhat complicated so I was trying to keep it simple as possible hoping it would be sufficient, but it looks like that his not the case so let me share with you the class definition:

```
public class Field : IField
{
    public FieldSpecification Specification { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}

public class FieldSpecification
{
        public int ColumnNumber { get; set; }
        public int Length { get; set; }
        public int StartPosition { get; set; }
        public int EndPosition { get { return StartPosition + Length - 1; } }
        public Justification Justification { get; set; }
        public char PadCharacter { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have a bunch of lines that conform to the ILine interface

```
public interface ILine
{
    List<IField> Fields { get; set; }
    int Credits { get; }
    int Debits { get; }
    BigInteger Hash { get; }
}
```

So technically above I show something like field.ColumnNumber, but it should be field.Specification.ColumnNumber.

The objective is to build fixed width files according to specifications that can change. So each line has a collection of fields with specifications, and then data can go into the content, and the specification can help do validation: formatting validation.

I was hoping there would be a way to sort subsets of lists using linq, but I may need to deconstruct my final collection of lines, sort it, then reconstruct the collection. I was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: Thank you Ondrej. I will be sure to do so in the future.

Comment: I don't suppose you could help us out by letting us know what the class definition of your data is?

Comment: So, what type is `Fields`?

Comment: not your question but... I know `BigInteger` will help avoid collisions but its never going to be as quick as `int`. Shouldn't you have a fast hash but an accurate equals.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [ThenBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.thenby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension.

Looking at your desired output, it seems something as simple as,

```
 var output = lines.Select(l => new
    {
        Col1 =  int.Parse(l.Fields.Find(f => f.ColumnNumber == 1).Content),
        Col2 =  l.Fields.Find(f => f.ColumnNumber == 2).Content,
        Col3 =  l.Fields.Find(f => f.ColumnNumber == 3).Content
    }).OrderBy(l => l.Col1).ThenBy(l => l.Col3);
```

would suffice.

---

If, for some reason, you only want to order the sub list when `Col1` is `6`,

```
 var output = lines.Select(l => new
    {
        Col1 =  int.Parse(l.Fields.Find(f => f.ColumnNumber == 1).Content),
        Col2 =  l.Fields.Find(f => f.ColumnNumber == 2).Content,
        Col3 =  l.Fields.Find(f => f.ColumnNumber == 3).Content
    }).OrderBy(l => l.Col1).ThenBy(l => l.Col1 == 6 ? l.Col3 : null);
```

---

One last caveat, depending on the type of `Fields` there is probably a better approach to all of this.

Comment: That would sort all subsets, not just the one he specifically wants to sort.

Comment: Yes that works, although I'm not sure there is any guarantee that `OrderBy(x => null)` preserves order. Another option would be to group by `Col1`, then `SelectMany` over the groupings, optionally calling `OrderBy` on each group if the predicate is met. Your solution is admittedly more concise.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done via the [ThenBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534743%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension method; in general, the concept is known as [lexicographical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

Answer (score 0):

If I can assume that you class definition is this:

```
public class Datum
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string[] Cols { get; set; }
}
```

Then I can define the data like this:

```
var data = new []
{
    new Datum() { ID = 1, Cols = new [] { "data", "data", "data", }, },
    new Datum() { ID = 5, Cols = new [] { "data", "data", }, },
    new Datum() { ID = 6, Cols = new [] { "data", "Chuck", }, },
    new Datum() { ID = 6, Cols = new [] { "data", "Chuck", }, },
    new Datum() { ID = 6, Cols = new [] { "data", "Jeffster", }, },
    new Datum() { ID = 6, Cols = new [] { "data", "Jeffster", }, },
    new Datum() { ID = 6, Cols = new [] { "data", "Grunke", }, },
    new Datum() { ID = 6, Cols = new [] { "data", "Gertrude", }, },
    new Datum() { ID = 8, Cols = new [] { "data", "data", }, },
    new Datum() { ID = 9, Cols = new [] { "data", }, },
};
```

And then I can sort like this:

```
var sorted =
    from d in data
    let key =
        String.Format("{0:0000}", d.ID)
        + (d.ID != 6 ? "" : "-" + d.Cols[1])
    orderby key
    select d;
```

I get these results:

[image: Results]